# How do I fix my issue with the Roblox Web API?

Tags: lua, roblox, webapi

I am trying to make a script that prints out the engagement earning for my game, I am using https://engagementpayouts.roblox.com/docs and it return a 401 Error when I run the script.

```
local http = game:GetService("HttpService")
local Url = "https://engagementpayouts.roproxy.com/v1/universe-payout-history?universeId=5704561876&startDate=2024-03-12&endDate=2024-02-28"
local Result = http:GetAsync(Url)

local data = http:JSONDecode(Result)["additionalProp1"]["payoutInRobux"]
print(data)
```

I haven't tried much because I only recently learned about using Web API in roblox.

Comment: 401 errors mean that your request doesn't have permission to access this information. This usually means that the request is missing a header that includes your security cookie.